# Button Hover Effect Not Work

Tags: css, button, effect, codepen

hello Firstly I am very sorry for my english. I want to add this effect to the site but not working. effect name slide from left but content: ""; not work help effect

```
  <div class="button-wrapper">
<div class="button slideleft"><span>Slide from left</span></div>

.button.slideleft:after {
  content: "";
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 70px;
  right: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transform: scale3d(1, 5, 1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 900ms cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform 900ms cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
  transition: transform 900ms cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
  transition: transform 900ms cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1), -webkit-transform 900ms cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
  width: 70px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.button.slideleft:hover span {
  color: white;
}
.button.slideleft:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(5, 3.5, 1);
          transform: scale3d(5, 3.5, 1);
}
```

[this effect](https://codepen.io/dominickolbe/pen/Ywwveg?editors=1100)

link

Comment: You need to provide more code. Your problem is likely to be that your CSS is not correctly linked with your HTML.

Comment: share your css too

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. The codepen link works well.

Comment: It is impossible to tell why it is not working you must provide CSS code with it.  It will be your CSS that is wrong not the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div class="button slideleft">` has a style of `position: absolute;`, you miss giving its parent element style of `position: relative`. Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.button-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```